# How to show Custom Instruction text on SharePoint library edit form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jsom

One of the Challenges I am having is to show certain text as of instructions on the upload form of a sharepoint library.
The idea is when a user clicks on the Upload button from the library itself, then select the file to upload, click ok and then on the next screen, they will have to populate some of the mandatory metadata. So on this particular form, i would like to show some text, can someone help me with the JS code for this.

Pleas see reference for adding custom text.

[image]

I guess this is doable by putting code on to the SharePoint library edit form, please help if someone knows. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A**ctually there's no need to write any code

- Go to the page which you need to add your instructions in
- Click the Settings Icon and click **Edit Page**
- Click **add a web part**
- Add a **Content Editor** web part
- in the **Content Editor** Add your Instructions text then click Stop Editing button.
  [image] 
  [image] 
  [image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am not looking to do it this way. I would want to show the instructions on the SharePoint upload form itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with Script Editor web part (approach similar to what A.Saéed proposed, but with Script Editor instead of Content Editor).

Steps would be:

Go to the EditForm page of your doc library (...DocLibrary/Forms/EditForm.aspx), click Edit Page in the top right gear menu, add Script Editor web part, click Edit Snippet and add this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ms-informationbar").after("<span>YOUR TEXT</span>");
}); 
</script>
```